# Windows authentication and email address retrieval using jsp

Tags: windows, jsp, email, authentication, waffle

I am trying to implement the windows authentication using a third party library 'Waffle'. The challenge I am facing is how to retrieve the mail id of the user if we know the User ID and the domain. For example I am able to get the User Id as XYZ\phembr and I want to get the mail address (phembrom@xyz.com in this case) from SMTP server. Following is the jsp code I am using and the output I am getting.

```
<%@page import="java.security.Principal" %>

<%@page import="waffle.windows.auth.WindowsAccount" %>

<%@page import="waffle.servlet.WindowsPrincipal" %>

<%@page import="com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Secur32" %>

<%@page import="com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Secur32Util" %>

<%

if (request.getParameter("logoff") != null) {

session.invalidate();

response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

return;

}

%>

<html>

<head>

<title>Protected Page for Examples</title>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

Welcome <b><%= Secur32Util.getUserNameEx(Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameDisplay)   %></b>    <br>

You are logged in as remote user <b><%= request.getRemoteUser() %></b> in session <b><%= session.getId() %></b>.<br>

You are impersonating user <b><%= Secur32Util.getUserNameEx(Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameSamCompatible) %> </b>.

<br><br>

<%

if (request.getUserPrincipal() != null) {

%>

Your user principal name is <b><%= request.getUserPrincipal().getName() %></b>.<br>



Your email is <b><%= Secur32Util.getUserNameEx(Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameUserPrincipal) %></b>.



<br><br>

<%

 } else {

%>

 No user principal could be identified.

 <br><br>

<%

}

%>

 </body>
```

The output I am getting is: (Note that I should have got phembrom@xyz.com and not phembr@xyz.com)

```
Welcome Prashant Kumar Hembrom

You are logged in as remote user XYZ\phembr in session DB5376CCEF5FA13F6059AC679F0B95BE.

You are impersonating user XYZ\phembr .



Your user principal name is XYZ\phembr.

Your email is phembr@xyz.com.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the FAQ: https://github.com/dblock/waffle/blob/master/Docs/faq/AdditionalActiveDirectoryInfo.md

You cannot do this with Waffle directly.On Windows this can be done by querying Active Directory with ADSI. This involves locating the user's record by the SID obtained from the logon and fetching any additional information.

Two implementations:

- https://gist.github.com/dblock/3004083
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/572278/Java-Retrieving-users-information-such-as-email-an